# How do I import files from other directory in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have been experimenting with python by creating some programs .The thing is, I have no idea how to import something OUT of the default python directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just read in a file and not import a module the documentation covers this extensively.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Specifically for Windows file systems you will need to do one of the following:

1.) Use forwardslashes vs backslashes. This should work with most OSes.

```
f = open("c:/somedir/somefile.txt", "r")
```

2.) Use a raw string.

```
f = open(r"c:\somedir\somefile.txt", "r")
```

3.) Escape the backslashes.

```
f = open("c:\\somedir\\somefile.txt", "r")
```

If you need to import a module to use in your program from outside your programs directory you can use the below information.

Python looks in the sys.path to see if the module exists there and if so does the import.  If the path where you files/modules are located is not in the sys.path, Python will raise an ImportError.  You can update the path programmatically by using the sys module.

```
import sys
dir = "path to mymodule"
if dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(dir)
import mymodule
```

You can check the current sys.path by using:

```
print(sys.path)
```

Example:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip',    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
>>> sys.path.append("/Users/ddrummond/pymodules")
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/Users/ddrummond/pymodules']
>>>
```

You can see that sys.path now contains '/Users/ddrummond/pymodules'.

Comment: Sir I am still not clear.Let me ask this way ,I want to read a txt file in Python located on my E drive can you give me the syntax that will help.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a link on how to read and write files from the official Python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

OK
So I did some heavy research and the conclusion is
if u want to access a file saved at different location
use
f = open('E:/somedir/somefile.txt', 'r')

r = f.read()

NOTE: Dont use '\' that were I went wrong.Our system addresses uses '\' So be careful